# Calling a messenger bound service from android Library

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a custom android library.

Calling My LIb as :

```
            mylib = new Mylib();
            JSONObject dict = new JSONObject();
            dict.put("Daata",1);
            mylib.initialize(dict);
```

Mylib code:

```
public class Mylib  {

    public Mylib() {
    }

    public void initialize(JSONObject message) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("done");
    }

}
```

Problem :

I want to start a non-activity class which can start messenger client side to interact with another app.
So I tried this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Mylib.this , MySecondLib.class );
```

I got this:

```
Cannot resolve constructor error
```

So, I tried extending my Mylib class to `extends AppCompatActivity`.
and writing

```
        Intent intent = new Intent( Mylib.this , MySecondLib.class );
        startActivity(intent);
```

and got this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

I see similar error when I pass:
`Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext() , MySecondLib.class );`

Now I pass the application context as parameter in the constructor of the Mylib class and run this :`Intent intent = new Intent( context , MySecondLib.class );`
But I still get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
```

So, I did `context.startActivity(intent);` 
and it worked for an activity class.

But what if the Mysecondlib is also a non-activity class and I want to start a messenger client side in the Mysecondlib.

So, I tried .. the official sample [Client side code for messenger service](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/MessengerServiceActivities.java).

Few changes had to be made:
`Replaced the bindservice with context.bindservice`

But Still unable to receive info from the server side.

Thanks a lot

Comment: "I want to start a non activity class" what does that mean? what do you expect "starting" such a class would do?

Comment: I want to start the client side for messenger bound service and As I have tried till now. It's not working in non activities classes.
Getting this error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it :

Add delay in the execution of `service.send()`

So the solution:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mservice.send(msg)
            }
        }, 1000);
```